# TextView not showing text in a particular listener

Tags: java, android

I am trying to have a textview display a message for 5 seconds and then disappear.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Date start;
    public Date end;
    Handler handle = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        Button endButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        // other variables
        final TextView errTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorTextView);
        final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

        final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //call function in MainActivity class
                handle.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        });

        final Thread errt = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                errTextView.setText("");
            }
        });

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){

                    if (start != null)
                        errTextView.setText("Timer Reset");
                        handler.postDelayed(errt, 5000);
                    start = new Date();
                    dateEditText.setText(df.format(start));
                    hoursEditText.setText("");
                    errTextView.setText("");

                    handle.post(t);

            }
        });


        endButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (start == null) {
                    errTextView.setText("Timer must be started before pressing Stop. Press Start.");
                }
                else {
                    start = null;
                }
                if(handle != null)
                    handle.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            }
        });
```

If the user presses the start button, start will get the current time and save it. So, if the user presses the start button again, the start button should not be null. If the user presses the twice, the condition should hold, `errTextView` should display "Timer reset", and the handler should tell the main thread to set `errTextView = ""` after 5 seconds. `errTextView` properly shows text in the stop button listener, but not in the start listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call

```
errTextView.setText("");
```

Every time startButton is pressed immediately. Therefore errTextView will always be empty once startButton is clicked